# Trouble with Selenium 2 Remote WebDriver and C# - Why won't my dictionary work?

Tags: c#, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, dictionary

First, a caveat: I'm brand new to C#, so please forgive me, if this is a ridiculously simple question. I'm converting some Selenium Python tests to C#, and I'm just getting started.

So, I have the following example in a test project, trying to get Selenium 2 working in C#:

```
public class Selenium2RemoteWebDriver
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pltfm = new Platform(PlatformType.Windows);

        var environment = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"username", "my-sauce-name"},
            {"accessKey", "my-sauce-key"},
            {"browserName", "iexplore"},
            {"version", "8"},
            {"platform", "Windows"},
            {"name","Hello, Sauce!"}
        };

        //foreach (var pair in environment)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        //}


        var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(environment);
        var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new Uri("http://my-sauce-id:my-sauce-key@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        var search = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        search.SendKeys("Hello, WebDriver");
        search.Submit();

        Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

When I run this test, I get the following message:

```
Test 'T:Selenium2_Testing.Selenium2RemoteWebDriver' failed: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

But when I uncomment the print statements, I can see the dictionary is complete:

```
Key: username, Value: my-sauce-id
Key: accessKey, Value: my-sauce-key
Key: browserName, Value: iexplore
Key: version, Value: 8
Key: platform, Value: Windows
Key: name, Value: Hello, Sauce!
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**  Apologies: I should have included that I am using:

Visual Studio 2010 (10.30319.1)
.Net Framework 4.0 (30319)
Selenium WebDriver 2.0b3 (the already compiled download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DesiredCapabilities object in the .NET bindings was recently (post 2.0b3) rewritten to correctly allow for passing a dictionary to define arbitary capabilities. The exact code change where the behavior was changed is visible at [this link](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=11833).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's something wrong with the assemblies I'm using. After compiling from the most recent source, and importing those binaries into the project, this problem ceased.

Comment: I'll post more details once I figure out what the delta is between the two sets of binaries.